# PHP - Generate a string based on regex

Tags: php

I would like to generate a string based on the regular expression I have.

The purpose of this function is when someone forgets their password, and completes the form for "Email New Password", I generate a random password that will be emailed to them. This new password must satisfy the conditions of my regex.

This is my regex:

```
'/.*^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[A-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$/'
```

Comment: And is the aim to do this with arbitrary regexes, or just this one specific regex?

Comment: There is a java library for this called Xeger. Although it us useless for PHP it might be a good starting point : http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

Comment: What I tried is creating multiple random expression generators; where on generates random alphabets that aren't capitalized, another that is capitalized, another one that generates numbers (3 digits) and another that is generating characters from a list. Though, you can see that concatenating them and processing them is too heavy. I was wondering if a single operation based on regex can be implemented. I'll look into the Java plugin, but I prefer using PHP alone :) Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [`Hoa\Regex` library](https://github.com/hoaproject/Regex)? It generates strings based on regular expression with an isotropic random approach.

Comment: This is a comment, not necessarily an answer.

Comment: So as an anwer, please check this article: http://mnt.io/P/2014-09-30_Generate_strings_based_on_regular_expressions.html :-).

Comment: Yes, it's long overdue, but your research paper was quite a good read. Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: @IvanEnderlin did Hoa\Regex works for "[0-9A-Za-z_-]{10}[048AEIMQUYcgkosw]" ? This is the Regex for the VideoID of youtube. (here the reference https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54443/format-for-id-of-youtube-video/101153#101153). The demo example form documentation works, but this one return "Undefined property: Hoa\Compiler\Exception\UnexpectedToken::$_tmpArguments". Maybe I shoud report on the github. Edit: the poster regex gives the same error. And yes, I'm aware that regex implement regex is a huge work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. No need for confusing regex:

```
function random_password( $length = 8 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?";
    $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $password;
}
```