# password generation using html and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

While clicking text field in the UI I need to display a random password in the text field.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please Enter Details " name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">        
    <!--<input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search here" onkeyup="drop_down(this.value);" name="val_text" id="val_text" onclick="drop_down_show('block');" onmouseout="drop_down_show('none');">-->
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Password</label>    
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" onblur="randomPassword()" readonly="" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $value['password']?>">                        
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What format would you like the password to be in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random password generator in PHP not returning password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359858/random-password-generator-in-php-not-returning-password)

Comment: So I guess somewhere you have a javascript function `randomPassword()`, can you provide its code also?

Comment: If all logic happens on the front-end there will be a much better way to generate a password from JavaScript. You can check this solution [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/2392957)

Comment: function randomPassword() {




    
   
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?";  
$length = rand(10, PHP_INT_MAX);  alert($length );
$password = substr( str_shuffle(sha1(rand() . time()) . $chars ), 0, $length );
alert();
 return $password;
}

Comment: @Thasneem and what `alert()` does?

Answer (score 1):

firstly generate password  and then use in your input

```
function randomPassword ($length = 8) 
{ 
  $genpassword = ""; 
  $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  
  $i = 0;  
  while ($i < $length) {  
    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1); 
    if (!strstr($genpassword, $char)) {  
      $genpassword .= $char; 
      $i++; 
    } 
  } 
  return $genpassword; 
} 

<input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo randomPassword(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are missing `;` after your PHP statements in the PHP inline blocks of code.

`<?php echo $value['whatever'] ?>`

...should become...

`<?php echo $value['whatever']; ?>`

However, if you want to display the PHP data only when a user selects the `input`, you want to be using the following code:

```
onfocus='this.value = <?php echo $value["whatever"]; ?>'
```

...or...

```
onclick='this.value = <?php echo $value["whatever"]; ?>'
```

...or if you only want it to be displayed when the `input` is empty or has no user input...

```
onfocus='this.placeholder = <?php echo $value["whatever"]; ?>'
onblur='this.placeholder = ""'
```